# Python+ Raspi: change LED color based on # of button presses

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

I wrote the following code to change the color of an LED on my breadboard from blue to violet to red, and then flash. When the program is run, the LED turns on and stays blue the entire time, regardless of the button presses.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

limit = 10
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

Rpin = 11
Bpin = 13
flow = 0

try:
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(15) == False:
            flow += 1
            print flow
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if flow >= limit:
            False
        if flow < 6*limit//10:
            print("blue")
            GPIO.setup(Bpin, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.HIGH)

        elif flow in range(6*limit//10, 8*limit//10):
            print("violet")
            GPIO.setup(Rpin, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.HIGH)

        elif flow in range(8*limit//10, limit):
            print("red")
            GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.LOW)

        else:
            print("flashing red...")
            GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(.2)
            GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(.2)
            GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(.2)
            GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(.2)
            GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
            break

except KeyboardInterrupt:   
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I can make the LED work correctly with key presses, and can count the button presses and print that value, but the two do not work in conjunction. I'm fairly certain that this is not a wiring issue, as other code can make these parts work on their own. I have read related posts on Stack and other websites and haven't found any code similar to mine, where an increment changes the color of the LED. As a relatively new python user, I suspect there is a problem in the code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time #added for sleep mode

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

Rpin = 11
Bpin = 13
flow = 0

GPIO.setup(Bpin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Rpin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.LOW)

limit = int(raw_input("How many gallons of water would you like to use                    for your shower?  "))
print("You may begin showering")
print limit

def flowmeter(f, l):
    if f == 0:
        print("off")
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.cleanup()
    if f < 6*l//10:
        print("blue")
        GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.HIGH)
    elif f in range(6*l//10, 8*l//10):
        print("violet")
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.HIGH)
    elif f in range(8*l//10, l):
        print("red")
        GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print("flashing red... time's up!")
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
        print("cleaning GPIO")
        GPIO.output(Rpin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(Bpin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.cleanup()
while True: 
    if GPIO.input(15) == False:
        flow += 1
        print("flow = %s" %flow)
        time.sleep(0.1) #prevents infinite pushes if held down for a few seconds
        flowmeter(flow,limit)
```

Comment: @PeterG does the flow += add anything? I was trying to increment that when the button (15) was pressed

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of flow every time the loop starts?

Comment: I'm doing that right now, but advice (or example code) on how to use a separate function to increment the flow value would be very helpful :) @barny

Comment: I have the code printing the value of flow every time the loop starts, flow is printing correctly each time, but the color of the light both printed to the console and of the actual LED is still blue.

Comment: The code has been fixed and will be posted above! I figured it out and I'll share the working program :D

Answer (score 0):

A debugging tip: if your code is never executing the code in an if statement, it's because the if test is always evaluating to false, and that's what you should investigate.

You need to read the python docs about the built-in range() function - it doesn't do what you are trying to do.

Instead of:

```
f in range(6*l//10, 8*l//10):
```

use comparisons e.g.

```
f >= 6*l//10 and f < 8*l//10
```

Comment: I tested the way you stated above and that does work, but the way I originally had it works just fine as well. Maybe it's a difference between Python versions?